# Matrices with Parallel Column Differences

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-calculus

I have two $p\times q$ matrices $A$ and $B$ that belong to the set:
$$
\{X\in R^{p\times q}: \sum_{i,j} X_{i,j}^2=1 ; \sum_{i,j} X_{i,j}=0 \}
$$

Also, showing the $i$'th column of $A$ by $a_i$, I know that
$$
(a_i - a_j) = c_{ij} (b_i-b_j) ; \qquad c_{ij}>0
$$ 
which means that $(a_i - a_j)$ and $(b_i - b_j)$ are parallel and in the same direction for all $i$ and $j$.

Can I conclude $A=B$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Imagine all the columns of $A$ and $B$ are multiples of a common vector. Can you come up with two different solutions $A_1,B_1$ and $A_2,B_2$ which both have mean zero of entries and sum of squared entries equal to 1? Further hint: Assume all columns of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are equal except for a certain number of  vectors, and similarly for corresponding column vectors of $B_1$ and $B_2$.

Comment: So, are you saying that I cannot conclude $A=B$? And is that a way to construct a counterexample?

Comment: @MMKK Let all columns of $A$ be equal to some $u\ne0$ and all columns of $B$ be equal to some $v\ne0$, where $u,v$ are linearly independent and the sum of all entries in each of $u, v$ is zero. Scale $u$ and $v$ so that their Euclidean norms are equal to $1/\sqrt{n}$. Then you get a counterexample.